# Exception thrown at (ntdll.dll) Access violation reading location when trying to run asio in 2 threads

Tags: multithreading, boost-asio

I am new to multithreading. I made program which works fine when single threaded.but when i add another thread to run asio io service "with main thread running same io service" it gives me this error :
`Exception thrown at  (ntdll.dll) Access violation reading location`
I use vs 2017 and i tried to use call stack to locate error  but it happens at ntdll.dll code which i do not have its source.
in addition ,i tried to exclude parts of code but it appears that error happens when async function returns from io service.
the program is large so i did not put code.
i want to know if there is way using vs2017 to link the ntdll.dll error to the part of my source code which lead to this error.
call stack at error onlu shows:
 `ntdll.dll!__except_handler4()
    ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler2@20()

    ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler@20()`

if files are required ,i will put their code.
thanks

UPDATE:
this function throws alot even though i launch it after locking mutex.
i think there is something wrong regarding memory usage.it gives me access violation .

```
std::string HTTPRequest::output_compressed_file_2(boost::shared_ptr<unsigned char> data_bin_buffer, size_t buffer_size, const char * file_name)
{
    std::string file_name_path_string = file_name; 
    std::ofstream ofs2(file_name_path_string, std::ios::binary); 
    ofs2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data_bin_buffer.get()), buffer_size);

    ofs2.close();
    return file_name_path_string;
}
```

it makes error related to memory .when i inspect call stack and threads , i found that it is called in both threads.in one thread it is just called ,in the other thread it is already called and it calls inside function sputn ,xsputn,copy and memcpy where throw happens.
i think that calling it in the other thread before it finishes in the first thread leads to error.i am trying to find any shared resource but i can not se any shared resource.this function is called inside another function which is called inside third function which is ran inside io service and this third function is member of class instance HttpRequest .
there are two instances of HttpRequest.
i can  not find the reason of memcpy error.
here is the code in which this function is called :

```
  void HTTPRequest::Execute(boost::asio::yield_context yield_r, std::string request_name, boost::shared_ptr<std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse>>> mHTTPClient_Responses_Map_shared_pointer)
{
    std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse>> & mHTTPClient_Responses_Map = boost::ref(*mHTTPClient_Responses_Map_shared_pointer).get() ;
    ptime startFetch = second_clock::local_time();
    //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error
    /*
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> cancel_lock(mCancelMutex);
    if (mWasCancelled)
    {
        cancel_lock.unlock();
        OnFinish(boost::system::error_code(boost::asio::error::operation_aborted));

        m_formatting_ostream << "Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl << " has been cancelled by the user at start of HTTPRequest::Execute coroutine." << std::endl;
        m_formatting_ostream.flush();
        ////allam2020 change UniqueSignalValue to url
        boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "c_E", request_name, m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
        //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
        m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();


        //p.set_value(request_name);
        //return request_name;
        //5-6-2020 i think i should return when cancelled
        return;

    }
    cancel_lock.unlock();
    */
    bool iterator_failed = true;
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    //5-7-2020 
    // Compose the request message.
    mRequestBuf += "GET " + mUri + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    // Add mandatory header.
    mRequestBuf += "Host: " + mHost + "\r\n";
    mRequestBuf += "\r\n";
    for (auto iterator_resolve : *mRequestSharedPtrVecResolverIterator)
    {
        //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

        BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog) << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "\t"<<"Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl <<" trying to send request using " << iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl<<"\n";


        //5-8-2020 changing continue to endless loop except for  404
        for (int mIrange2 =1; mIrange2 < ATTEMPTS; ++mIrange2)
        {
            ++HTTPRequest::mIrange ;
            resolver_iterator iterator_connect = boost::asio::async_connect(mSock, iterator_resolve, yield_r[ec]);////allam 2020 this gets us back to io_stream_run

            if (ec.value() == boost::system::errc::errc_t::success)
            {               
                ////allam 2020
                iterator_failed = false;
                //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

                boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> cancel_lock(mCancelMutex);
                if (mWasCancelled)
                {
                    cancel_lock.unlock();
                    OnFinish(boost::system::error_code(boost::asio::error::operation_aborted));

                    m_formatting_ostream << "Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl << " has been cancelled by the user after returning from async_connect inside HTTPRequest::Execute using"<< iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
                    m_formatting_ostream.flush();
                    //4-26-2020 
                    //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "cancel_async_connect_Execute", iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string);
                    boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "c_a_c_E", request_name,m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                    //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
                    m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();


                    //p.set_value(request_name);
                    //return request_name;
                    return;
                }               
                cancel_lock.unlock();

                // Send the request message.
                SendRequest(yield_r);
            }
            else if (ec.value() != boost::system::errc::errc_t::success)
            {
                OnFinish(ec);   
                //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

                BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog) <<"Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl <<" failed after trying " << mIrange2 << "times" << " to async_connect inside HTTPRequest::Execute " << std::endl;

                continue;
            }

            if (mContinue_for==true)
            {
                mContinue_for = !(mContinue_for);               
                //5-5-2020 async timer
                mAsyncTimer.expires_from_now(boost::asio::chrono::milliseconds(mIrange));//5-5-2020
                mAsyncTimer.async_wait(yield_r);

                //5-7-2020
                if (mSendRequest == 0)
                {
                    if (mReadStatusLine == 0)
                    {
                        if (mHttp_1_1 == 0)
                        {
                            if (mStatusCodeNot200 == 0)
                            {
                                if (mReadResponseHeaders == 0)
                                {
                                    if (mReadResponseBody == 0)
                                    {
                                        ////allam2020 4-4-2020 no error present and response is recieved in its mHTTPResponse SO DO NOTHING 
                                    }
                                    else if (mReadResponseBody != 0)
                                    {
                                        mIrange2--;
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (mReadResponseHeaders != 0)
                                {
                                    mIrange2--;

                                }
                            }
                            else if (mStatusCodeNot200 != 0)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        else if (mHttp_1_1 != 0)
                        {
                            mIrange2--;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (mReadStatusLine != 0)
                    {
                        mIrange2--;
                    }
                }
                else if (mSendRequest != 0)
                {
                    mIrange2--;
                }

                continue;
            }

            // Response is correct.
            //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

            m_formatting_ostream << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "\t" << "Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl << " Fetched " << mUrl << " completed in : " << (second_clock::local_time() - startFetch) << "with HTTP code :" << mResponsePtr->get_status_code() << "\t" << "and the code reasonPhrase is :" << HttpStatus::reasonPhrase(static_cast<int>(mResponsePtr->get_status_code())) << "with certain resolver iterator " << iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
            m_formatting_ostream.flush();

            //4-26-2020 
            //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "http_request_completed", HttpStatus::reasonPhrase(static_cast<int>(mResponsePtr->get_status_code())), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
            boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "req_comp", HttpStatus::reasonPhrase(static_cast<int>(mResponsePtr->get_status_code())), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
            //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
            m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();


            if (mResponsePtr->get_response_buf().size() <= 0)
            {
                //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

                m_formatting_ostream << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "\t" << "Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl << " Fetched " << mUrl << " with Buffer for " << mUrl << " is empty  " << "\n" << "with HTTP code :" << mResponsePtr->get_status_code() << "\n" << "and the code reasonPhrase is :" << HttpStatus::reasonPhrase(static_cast<int>(mResponsePtr->get_status_code())) << std::endl;
                m_formatting_ostream.flush();

                //4-26-2020
                //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "http_request_completed_empty", HttpStatus::reasonPhrase(static_cast<int>(mResponsePtr->get_status_code())), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "req_comp_empty", HttpStatus::reasonPhrase(static_cast<int>(mResponsePtr->get_status_code())), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
                m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();

            }

            //continue work on response

            mHTTPRequest_response_name = "response_" + request_name;
            mHTTPClient_Responses_Map[mHTTPRequest_response_name] = GetResponseSharedPtr();
            //4-24-2020 here i will save to file
            std::size_t pos = mUrl.find("h_ticks.bi5");      // position of "h_ticks.bi5" in str
            std::string mHTTPRequest_file_name = mUrl.substr(pos - 2);     // get from "h_ticks.bi5" to the end 
            std::string mHTTPRequest_hour_name = mUrl.substr(pos - 2,2);     // get from "h_ticks.bi5" to the end   
            date mHTTPRequest_file_name_ptime_epoch_date =mHTTPRequest_HTTPClient_shared_pointer->m_HttpClient_Day_Full_DateGet() ;
            ptime mHTTPRequest_file_name_ptime_epoch(mHTTPRequest_file_name_ptime_epoch_date, pt::hours(std::stoi(mHTTPRequest_hour_name)));

            std::string compressed_file_path_string =output_compressed_file(mResponsePtr->get_response_buf(), mHTTPRequest_file_name);
            path compressed_file_path{ compressed_file_path_string };
            read_bi5_main(compressed_file_path, mHTTPRequest_file_name_ptime_epoch);
            break;
        }

        //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error
        /*
        //the following conditions test the result of send request
        if (mSendRequest == 0)
        {
            if (mReadStatusLine == 0)
            {
                if (mHttp_1_1 == 0)
                {
                    if (mStatusCodeNot200 == 0)
                    {
                        if (mReadResponseHeaders == 0)
                        {
                            if (mReadResponseBody == 0)
                            {
                                ////allam2020 4-4-2020 no error present and response is recieved in its mHTTPResponse SO DO NOTHING 
                            }
                            else if (mReadResponseBody != 0)
                            {
                                m_formatting_ostream << "Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl << " has failed completely after trying" << ATTEMPTS << "times" << " to async_read inside HTTPRequest::ReadResponseBody to get ResponseBody  " << "with certain resolver iterator " << iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
                                m_formatting_ostream.flush();
                                //4-26-2020
                                //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "failed_async_read_inside_HTTPRequest_ReadResponseBody", "requestFailed_ReadResponseBody_Iterator_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string);
                                //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "fail_a_r_in_RRB", "reqFail_RRB_It_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(),m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                                boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "f_ar_RRB", "_" + request_name, m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                                //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
                                m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();

                            }
                        }
                        else if (mReadResponseHeaders != 0)
                        {
                            m_formatting_ostream << "Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl << " has failed completely after trying" << ATTEMPTS << "times" << " to async_read_until inside HTTPRequest::ReadResponseHeadersto get ResponseHeaders " << "with certain resolver iterator " << iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
                            m_formatting_ostream.flush();
                            //4-26-2020
                            //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "failed_async_read_until_inside_HTTPRequest_ReadResponseHeaders", "requestFailed_ReadResponseHeaders_Iterator_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string);
                            //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "fail_a_r_until_in_RRH", "reqFail_RRH_It_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                            boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "f_aru_RRH", "_" + request_name, m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                            //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
                            m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();

                        }
                    }
                    else if (mStatusCodeNot200 != 0)
                    {
                        m_formatting_ostream << "Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl << " has failed completely after" << ATTEMPTS << "times" << " to async_read_until inside HTTPRequest::ReadStatusLine because of status_code not 200:" << http_errors::invalid_response << "the error code is :" << mStatusCode << "\n" << "and the error reasonPhrase is :" << HttpStatus::reasonPhrase(static_cast<int>(std::stoul(mStatusCode))) << "with certain resolver iterator " << iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
                        m_formatting_ostream.flush();
                        //4-26-2020
                        //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "failed_StatusCodeNot200_inside_HTTPRequest_ReadStatusLine", "requestFailed_ReadStatusLine_StatusCodeNot200:StatusCode_is_" + mStatusCode + "with_Iterator_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string);
                        //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "fail_Not200_in_RSL", "reqFail_RSL_Not200:St_is_" + mStatusCode + "with_It_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                        boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "f_N200_RSL", "_" + mStatusCode + "_" + request_name, m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                        //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
                        m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();

                    }
                }
                else if (mHttp_1_1 != 0)
                {
                    ////4-2-2020
                    m_formatting_ostream << "Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl << " after trying " << ATTEMPTS << "times" << " to async_read_until inside HTTPRequest::ReadStatusLine because of bad not http/1.1 version response" << mHTTP_Version << "recieved with certain resolver iterator " << iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
                    m_formatting_ostream.flush();
                    //4-26-2020
                    //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "failed_Http_1_1_inside_HTTPRequest_ReadStatusLine", "requestFailed_ReadStatusLine_Http_1_1_Iterator_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string);
                    //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "fail_Http_1_1_in_RSL", "reqFail_RSL_Http_1_1_It_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                    boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "f_H11_RSL", "_" + request_name, m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                    //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
                    m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();

                }
            }
            else if (mReadStatusLine != 0)
            {
                ////4-2-2020
                m_formatting_ostream << "Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl << " failed completely after trying " << ATTEMPTS << "times" << " to async_read_until inside HTTPRequest::ReadStatusLine  with certain resolver iterator " << iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
                m_formatting_ostream.flush();
                //4-26-2020
                //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "failed_async_read_until_inside_HTTPRequest_ReadStatusLine", "requestFailed_ReadStatusLine_Iterator_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "fail_a_r_u_in_RSL", "reqFail_RSL_It_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "f_aru_RSL", "_" + request_name, m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "fail_aru_in_RSL", "_" , m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
                //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
                m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();

            }
        }
        else if (mSendRequest != 0)
        {
            ////4-2-2020
            m_formatting_ostream << "Request #" << this->GetId() << " for " << mUrl << " failed after trying " << ATTEMPTS << "times" << " to async_write inside HTTPRequest::SendRequest  with certain resolver iterator " << iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
            m_formatting_ostream.flush();
            //4-26-2020
            //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "failed_async_write_inside_HTTPRequest_SendRequest", "requestFailed_SendRequest_Iterator_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
            //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "fail_aw_in_SR", "_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
            boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "f_aw_SR", "_" + request_name, m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
            //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
            m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();

        }
        */


        if (iterator_failed == true)
        {
            //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

            m_formatting_ostream << "Request failed for " << mUrl << " after trying " << ATTEMPTS << "times" << " to async_connect inside HTTPRequest::Execute with certain resolver iterator "<< iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
            m_formatting_ostream.flush();
            ////allam 2020 i might need to pass iterator resolve which has failed
            //4-26-2020
            //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "failed_async_connect_inside_HTTPRequest_Execute", "requestFailed_Iterator_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string(), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
            //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "f_ac_E", "_" + iterator_resolve->endpoint().address().to_string()+ request_name, m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex); 
            std::string string_replace = { mSock.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() };
            replace(string_replace, ".", "");
            boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "f_ac_E", "_" + string_replace + request_name, m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);
            //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
            m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();

            continue;////allam 2020 here i should continue for next iterator
        }
    }
    //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

    if (iterator_failed == true)
    {
        m_formatting_ostream << "Request failed for " << mUrl << " after trying " << ATTEMPTS << "times" << " to async_connect inside HTTPRequest::Execute with ALL resolver iterators" << std::endl;
        m_formatting_ostream.flush();
        ////allam 2020 i might need to pass iterator resolve which has failed
        //4-26-2020
        //boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, "failed_async_connect_inside_HTTPRequest_Execute", "requestFailed_Iterator_" + GetmUrlLogger(), m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);////allam2020 ?????i might need to change this from GetmUrlLogger to request name argument of Execute???????????????????4-2-2020
        boost_log_function(mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer, mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str, "f_ac_E", "_" + GetmUrlLogger()+ request_name,m_formatting_ostream_string, mBOOST_LOGMutex);////allam2020 ?????i might need to change this from GetmUrlLogger to request name argument of Execute???????????????????4-2-2020
                                                                                                //5-16-2020m_formatting_ostream.clear();
        m_formatting_ostream_string.clear();    

    }

    ////allam2020 should i put if conditions for mSendRequest ....mReadResponseBody????? to identify final complete error at these functions and end of 5 attempts

}
```

and this is function read_bi5_main:

```
int HTTPRequest::read_bi5_main(boost::filesystem::path p, ptime epoch)
{
    unsigned char *buffer;
    size_t buffer_size;

    int counter;

    size_t raw_size = 0;

    std::string filename_string = p.generic_string();
    path p2 = p;
    p2.replace_extension(".bin");
    std::string filename_string_2_bin =p2.generic_string() ;

    path p3 = p;
    p3.replace_extension(".csv");
    std::string filename_string_2_csv = p3.generic_string();

    const char *filename = filename_string.c_str();
    const char *filename_2_bin = filename_string_2_bin.c_str();

    const char *filename_2_csv = filename_string_2_csv.c_str();

    if (fs::exists(p) && fs::is_regular(p)) 
    {
        buffer_size = fs::file_size(p);
        buffer = new unsigned char[buffer_size];
    }
    else {
        //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

        BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog) << "Error: couldn't access the data file. |"
            << filename << "|" << std::endl;

        return 2;
    }

    std::ifstream fin(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
    //fin.open(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
    fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), buffer_size);
    fin.close();

    //5-11-2020 the next line will be commented and put in HTTPCLIent constructor
    //mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str= mHTTPRequest_HTTPClient_shared_pointer->Get_mHttpClient_HttpSymbolPrepareGet_shared_pointer()->mSymbol_strGet() ;
    std::size_t pos = mHTTPRequest_Symbol_str.find("JPY");// position of "h_ticks.bi5" in str
    double PV;
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        PV = PV_YEN_PAIR;
    }
    else
    {
        PV = PV_DOLLAR_PAIR;
    }
    boost::shared_ptr<unsigned char> data_bin_buffer = boost::make_shared<unsigned char>() ;
    //boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> read_bi5_to_bin_lock(m_read_bi5_to_binMutex);
    n47::tick_data *data = n47::read_bi5_to_bin(
        buffer, buffer_size, epoch, PV, &raw_size, data_bin_buffer.get());
    //read_bi5_to_bin_lock.unlock();
    //5-11-2020 here i will save binary file
    std::string file_name_path_string=output_compressed_file_2(data_bin_buffer, raw_size, filename_2_bin);
    path file_name_path_2{ file_name_path_string }; 
    buffer_size = 0;    
    if (fs::exists(file_name_path_2) && fs::is_regular(file_name_path_2)) 
    {
        //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

        BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog) << boost::this_thread::get_id() <<"\t we can access the data .bin file. |"
            << filename_2_bin << "| with size ="<< fs::file_size(file_name_path_2) << std::endl;

    }
    else {
        //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

        BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog) << "Error: couldn't access the data .bin file. |"
            << filename_2_bin << "|" << std::endl;

        return 2;
    }

    n47::tick_data_iterator iter;

    //5-11-2020 here i will save file.csv from data which is pointer to vector to pointers to ticks

    if (data == 0) {
        //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

        BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog) << "Failure: Failed to load the data!" << std::endl;

        //5-14-2020 file is empty
        //return 0;
    }
    //5-15-2020 take care that without else ,error happens with empty files because data is pointer to vector of pointers to ticks .so when data is made inside read_bi5 ,it is made as null pointer and later it is assigned to vector if file has ticks.if file does not have ticks ,then it is just returned as null pointer .so when dereferencing null pointer we got error
    else if (data->size() != (raw_size / n47::ROW_SIZE)) {
        //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

        BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog) << "Failure: Loaded " << data->size()
            << " ticks but file size indicates we should have loaded "
            << (raw_size / n47::ROW_SIZE) << std::endl;

        //5-14-2020 file is empty
        //return 0;
    }

    //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

    BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog) << "time, bid, bid_vol, ask, ask_vol" << std::endl;

    counter = 0;
    std::ofstream out_csv(filename_string_2_csv);
    if (data == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (data != 0)
    {
        ////read_bi5_to_bin_lock.lock();

        for (iter = data->begin(); iter != data->end(); iter++) {
            //5-11-2020 here i will save file.csv from data which is pointer to vector to pointers to ticks>>>>>>>here i should open file stream for output and save data to it
            out_csv << ((*iter)->epoch + (*iter)->td) << ", "
                << (*iter)->bid << ", " << (*iter)->bidv << ", "
                << (*iter)->ask << ", " << (*iter)->askv << std::endl;
            //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

            BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog) <<
                boost::this_thread::get_id() << "\t"<<((*iter)->epoch + (*iter)->td) << ", "
                << (*iter)->bid << ", " << (*iter)->bidv << ", "
                << (*iter)->ask << ", " << (*iter)->askv << std::endl;

            counter++;
        }
        ////read_bi5_to_bin_lock.unlock();

    }
    out_csv.close();
    //5-13-2020

    //??5-17-2020 isolate multithreaded error

    BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog) << ".end." << std::endl << std::endl
        << "From " << raw_size << " bytes we read " << counter
        << " records." << std::endl
        << raw_size << " / " << n47::ROW_SIZE << " = "
        << (raw_size / n47::ROW_SIZE) << std::endl;


    delete data;
    delete[] buffer;    
    return 0;
}
```

this function uses lzma decompression files which i didnot include.if required i will include.
i wish you give me mind map of how to reach error source.
thanks

UPDATE:
this is read_bi5_to_bin

```
tick_data* read_bi5_to_bin(
    unsigned char *lzma_buffer, size_t lzma_buffer_size, pt::ptime epoch,
    float point_value, size_t *bytes_read, unsigned char* buffer_decompressed) {
    tick_data *result = 0;

    // decompress
    int status;
    buffer_decompressed = n47::lzma::decompress(lzma_buffer,
        lzma_buffer_size, &status, bytes_read);

    if (status != N47_E_OK) 
    {
        bytes_read = 0;
    }
    else {
        // convert to tick data (with read_bin).
        result = read_bin(buffer_decompressed, *bytes_read, epoch, point_value);
        //delete[] buffer;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to show your code. You have [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), usually because you didn't make sure that lifetime of objects remains during async operations (like the buffer).

Comment: @sehe i searched how  to upload code but they say it is not allowed to upload files....so i do not how to show code.i am trying to isolate the error. but it happens at ntdll.dll which is outside my source code.i do not know what to do.

Comment: Your code is what triggers it so find out what function call triggers the error. And you can just show code in your question text. That's how everybody does it

Comment: i will try to isolate the error and show the code triggering it.thanks

Comment: @sehe i included some code i think it might be source for error.thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. Now I [remember](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61409432/85371). I still see the same problems in the code. Mainly, it is (vastly) over-complicated. I see many things worth noting, but I'm not sure it will help, seeing that the last time didn't help much either: [boose wait_for_any with asio io-service...how can i return future suitable for wait_for_any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405432/boose-wait-for-any-with-asio-io-service-how-can-i-return-future-suitable-for-w/61409432#61409432)

1. `boost::shared_ptr<unsigned char> data_bin_buffer = boost::make_shared<unsigned char>() ;`

   Why are you creating "buffers" of single byte? Why are you creating them as a shared resource?
2. your `read_bi5_main` does it almost correctly, and seems to be copied from https://github.com/ninety47/dukascopy/blob/8654ad197bdf55579544cf71735369f0d227569f/test/test_read_bi5.cpp#L42 or similar.
3. `n47::read_bi5` returns the bytes read in `raw_size`, and you use that as a valid buffer size.

   I cannot find documentation for `read_bi5_to_bin`, and consequently don't know how **exactly** it uses that bin_buffer, BUT I can tell that you're likely doing bogus with it:

   ```
   output_compressed_file_2(data_bin_buffer, raw_size, filename_2_bin);
   ```

   Here you're treating `data_bin_buffer` as if it points to a buffer of any size `raw_size` where the only valid sizes could ever be `1` or `0` (because you never allocate more).

   So that's invoking [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

   > Even if you made it so that `read_bi5_to_bin` is safe for a bin buffer of 1 byte, that would be pretty useless, as one `n47::ROW_SIZE` is 20 bytes.
4. In

   ```
   resolver_iterator iterator_connect = boost::asio::async_connect(mSock, iterator_resolve, yield_r[ec]);
   ```

   you didn't heed the advice to not iterate resolver results manually. Now you're doing everything double (if you had 5 resolver results, you try connecting `(ATTEMPTS-1)*(5+4+3+2+1)` times).
   Apart from `ATTEMPTS-1` looking like a mistake (the loop condition seems wrong or the loop-var initializer should be 0?), this is certainly not what you want/need. However, the many (double) increments/decrements of `mIrange2` [sic] make it really hard to predict how many attempts are gonna be made, and how they will be numbered according to the log statements. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if there was a potential for an infinite loop.
5. There's `mUri` and `mUrl`. This is bound to lead to errors.

### SUMMARIZING

I think that #3 from the list is your source of a crash here.
In related news, I created a sample for another recent question that somewhat reminds me of your code: [How to read data from Internet using muli-threading with connecting only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787334/how-to-read-data-from-internet-using-muli-threading-with-connecting-only-once/61809655#61809655)

Maybe it helps you see how to create **vastly** simpler code to do what you're trying to achieve. By that I mean, you should end up with 20% of the code.

Comment: you are marvelous.i love you :)

Comment: `How on earth did mSock get "renamed" to mlock? This seems very sloppy` this line did not change??it is still mSock

Comment: `boost::shared_ptr<unsigned char> data_bin_buffer = boost::make_shared<unsigned char>() ;` i did not mean to make it as single byte buffer.i just did not change much of the original code ,and i had transfer the data from inside read_bi5 so i just changed read_bi5 to take the raw pointer of this shared pointer to unsigned char using shared_pointer.get then i use this pointer to pass contents of file to  output_compressed_file_2 where sometimes it works and other times it just has single char?? i thought that i just need pointer and size...how can i allocate to pointer??it is not array

Comment: @ahmedallam then make it an array: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr#Array_version.2C_unique_ptr.3CT.5B.5D.3E or https://stackoverflow.com/a/25969615/85371. Keep in mind shared-pointers should be avoided 99% of the time. If you need one for the async-operation, have 1that contains all the shared resources.

Comment: @ahmedallam Re. `mlock`: Ah. No idea how that happened then. My UndoTree shows that apparently it happened in a clang-tidy pass o.O (see before and after [before and after pics](https://imgur.com/a/K0Skgv2)). I may try this out again just to see whether it can be reproduced :/

Comment: Okay, so indeed my `clang-tidy` is misconfigured for code that doesn't compile: https://imgur.com/JArQZ98 Thanks for helping me realize that. It also made the assignments to the `mIrange`/`mIrange2` variables more confusing than required.

Comment: i did not ignore your previous advice about not using shared pointers But i try not to change the original code  i find online so that i do not get surprise.i try to just modify it as short as i can and debug to make sure no errors happened.i am not very good at c++ yet.i hope to be one day.i did not make an array because i can not pass array as argument to function.or return it from function.it had to be pointer .so i made data_bin_buffer.then i converted it to shared pointer so that not to leak. the pointer should be pointing to heap made array in lzma decompress function.

Comment: so now if i want to correct the data_bin_buffer ,how can i make it acceptable to ofstream write function and in same time it contains decompressed bytes.you said it is allocated 1 byte.i did not allocate any thing .i just make shared it then passed it to read_bi5_to_bin..i want it to have raw_size size ....this error sometimes happens and other times not. do you think that heap array is changed in the other thread sothat when data_bin_buffer pointer try to read it ,it finds changed data and so crash??!!

Comment: "But i try not to change the original code i find online so that i do not get surprise.i try to just modify it as short as i can" - find other code online :) Or get over your fear and discover that if you don't log everything twice, litter the code with [superstitious comments](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/07/comments-are-not-version-control/), using every library you can think of, repeating `BOOST_LOG((*mHTTPRequest_LoggingInstance_shared_pointer).mloggerCoutLog)` every 10 lines, structuring your code so you can /see/ what it does and why it must be correct...  you can actually do this

Comment: `i did not allocate any thing .i just make shared it` -> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared#Notes

Comment: i made new question with detailed steps of functions involved.i wish to solve the problem of data_bin_buffer which lead to access violation.this is the new question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917127/passing-array-as-return-from-function-in-multi-threaded-app`

Comment: now i see it clearly that data_bin_buffer is null when it is inside output_compressed_file_2 ....this is the problem...how do i make it point to buffer "outbuffer" in n47::lzma::decompress??

Answer (score 0):

I found that I am passing pointer to unsigned char "data_bin_buffer" as argument to function read_bi5_to_bin ,
which is some how treated as variable ,
which is copied inside function and the copy is assigned the array,
 but the passed pointer remained null.
so I changed data_bin_buffer from pointer unsigned char to value unsigned char,
and then took its address by &,
 and passed this to read_bi5_to_bin,
 and problem solved.
but I have another problem now.should i delete or delete[] &data_bin_buffer???
and if I delete it "not the array delete",what happens to the array on the heap pointed to by &data_bin_buffer???

Comment: Your text will be more legible without so many question marks, and perhaps more capitalization and whitespace, I think it's time to [read a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @sehe i managed solve the current problem.thanks alot for your help.the problem of designing the code is what i can not find good resource to start reading.i think i need to read about design patterns.i want something which helps me design my code in simpler way.I am self learning ,so sometimes i got lost.now I am refactoring the code ,"after the joy of seeing it working :)".I will try to achieve the points you remarked in this question and the last one.thanks again for your patience.if you have any suggestion related to certain "how to design" book , I will be very thankful.